# shopify post back to merchant site from hosted payment gateway(payment gateway is created by us) if transaction fails/succeeds

Tags: payment-gateway, shopify

We have created a payment Gateway based on the following doc mentioned on the Shopify site:

https://docs.shopify.com/hosted-payment-sdk/develop-gateway

And when user checks out it goes to my payment gateway site, but now, when i redirect the user from my site to Shopify if transaction fails/succeeds,then i get a timeout error.

As per the doc i need to redirect to following URL with below response values:

Cancel URL: myshopify.io

Success URL:  myshopify.io/orders/1/done

Response Values: x_account_id, x_reference, x_currency, x_test, x_amount, x_gateway_reference, , x_timestamp, x_result, x_signature

NOTE: I am posting to shopify from my local machine and fetching values from shopify to my local machine's ip

Please help on the same...

Comment: Are my success and Cancel URL wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Print the `$_POST` on the page where you receive the request and you'll see that all the required information is there.